# How to view single image with different size on angular12 app for desktop/ mobile /tab devices

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular-material, angular12

User has been uploaded 1 image irrespective of size in pixel but i want to view this image in different sizes on desktop / mobile / tab it means for different sizes of screen it should auto adjust the width and length as per the screen size how can i achieve this in angular12.

Comment: The image will respect the container in which it is placed, so if you set the width and height of image as 100% and then make the container size based on different viewports, should work you, unless I do not exactly understand your question